# Adding images to react/gatsby markdown html/md mixed files

Tags: html, reactjs, markdown, gatsby

**Part 1:**

I have been searching for a while now and have found a few options that work in markdown but not how I would like. I am looking for a way to add images to a markdown files HTML.

Currently this works in the md files:

```
![description](../img/splash/homepage-tall.jpg)
```

But, I am trying to add a class to the above with no success.

What I have tried so far:

```
![img description][../img/splash/homepage-tall.jpg]{: .img-fluid }

![img description](../img/splash/homepage-tall.jpg){.img-fluid}

![img description][../img/splash/homepage-tall.jpg]{: class=img-fluid }
```

Can a class be added to markdown?

---

**Part 2:**

I even tried going the direct HTML route but, the relative path does not work. Is there a way to link the images using HTML in a markdown file?

```
<img class="module" src="../img/splash/homepage-tall.jpg" alt=" "/>
```

Comment: Have you tried this workaround https://github.com/russross/blackfriday/issues/364?
Also, which Markdown engine is used by Gatsby? That information could give you a better answer.

Comment: Yeah, it just prints '{.my-class}' next to the image. Not sure about the engine, I can research

Comment: @FernandoMontoya Gatsby uses [remarkjs](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark) for markdown

Comment: @brooksrelyt Hi there, long time no see! Have you tried just writing html directly in markdown? `<img class="module" src="...">` it should work

Comment: Hi @DerekNguyen I tried adding the html but the src is not found

Comment: ah, right, I guess it's because of the relative path. I have a plugin that automatically attach classes to markdown block, but there might be something that'll manipulate the src for you... let me take a look

Comment: @brooksrelyt are you using [`gatsby-remark-images`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-remark-images/?=remark%20images)? I've just tested it out & it seems to work

Comment: @DerekNguyen the relative path works or the markdown image with classes?

Comment: both works for me -- image with relative path + class name

Comment: @DerekNguyen hm, I got it to work using this method just now. But, the relative links are not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195642/discussion-between-derek-nguyen-and-brooksrelyt).